# How do I compare two files with a shell script?

Tags: bash, unix, script

Given two files, I want to write a shell script that reads each line from file1 and checks if it is there in file2. If a line is not found it should output two files are different and exit. The files can contain words numbers or anything. For example :

file1 :

```
Hi!
1234
5678
1111
hello
```

file2:

```
1111
5678
1234
Hi!
hello
```

In this case two files should be equal. if file2 has "hello!!!" instead of "hello" then the files are different. I'm using bash script. How can I do this. It is not important that I need to do it in a nested loop but that's what I thought is the only way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In bash:

```
diff --brief <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: What if the file is a csv file. would sorting still work ?

Comment: `sort` doesn't care about the exact contents unless you tell it to.

Comment: Is it possible to find which lines differ ?

Comment: Remove `--brief` and add format options, e.g. `-u`.

Answer (score 12):

`diff` sets its exit status to indicate if the files are the same or not. The exit status is accessible in the special variable `$?`. You can expand on Ignacio's answer this way:

```
diff --brief <(sort file1) <(sort file2) >/dev/null
comp_value=$?

if [ $comp_value -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "do something because they're different"
else
    echo "do something because they're identical"
fi
```

Comment: You can just do `if diff ... >/dev/null` without the brackets and variable.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst `diff` is a perfectly fine answer, I'd probably use `cmp` instead which is specifically for doing a byte by byte comparison of two files.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/cmp

Because of this, it has the added bonus of being able to compare binary files.

```
if cmp -s "file1" "file2"
then
   echo "The files match"
else
   echo "The files are different"
fi
```

I'm led to believe it's faster than using `diff` although I've not personally tested that.

Comment: Wouldn't the "files are different" case go first? The if test asks if something is true, ie, a nonzero return code. If the files match, cmp returns 0 (per the manpage), and so that should be the second case.

Comment: @user8162 What you say makes sense, however I've just tested it and that is the right way around. I'm not sure why that is the case to be honest.

Comment: @user8162 `0` means success on the shell and thus true. `if <condition>; then` will be executed if <condition> is true and for commands that is if they return success. `/bin/true` always exists with `0` and `/bin/false` always exists with `1`. That's because the exit code is interpreted as an error code and error code `0` means no error == success.

Answer (score 2):

Should also work :

```
comm -3 file1 file2
```

I think this is enough characters for an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Adding this because I think the [[ ]] && || construct is pretty neat:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ `diff ${HOME}/file1 ${HOME}/file2` ]] &&  
   (echo "files different") ||
   (echo "files same")
```